# How can I prevent CKEditor from enclosing URLs in quotes?

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

Due to a very specific requirement, I need to prevent CKEditor from rewriting links with quotation marks around the URL. For example, if I input:

```
<a href=TEST123>TEST123</a>
```

CKEditor rewrites it to:

```
<a href="TEST123">TEST123</a>
```

I currently have the following plugins in my distribution, although adding or removing different plugins to meet this requirement would not be a problem:

```
basicstyles, button, clipboard, dialog, dialogui, enterkey, 
entities, fakeobjects, floatingspace, indent, indentlist, 
link, list, resize, sourcearea, toolbar, undo, wysiwygarea
```

Before I get lectured about how bad of an idea this is (you're preaching to the choir here), know that this is a REQUIREMENT for a very specific implementation of the Keyora web platform. There's nothing I can do to get around the requirement, since it is already compiled into someone else's code. I just need to make it work, somehow. Is there any way to do this with CKEditor?

Thanks!

Comment: If you leave the quotes off some browsers will insert them .... not much you can do to stop it. Only solution I can think of is parse the html strings prior to submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. The trick is to copy the basicWriter function (located in /ckeditor/core/htmlparser/basicwriter.js) into your /config.js file and apply a small customization to it, like so:

**Original**

```
CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter = CKEDITOR.tools.createClass( {

...

this._.output.push( ' ', attName, '="', attValue, '"' );

...

} );
```

**Customized**

```
CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter = CKEDITOR.tools.createClass( {

...

if ( attName == 'href' ) {
    this._.output.push( ' ', attName, '=', attValue, '' );
    } else {
    this._.output.push( ' ', attName, '="', attValue, '"' );
    }

...

} );
```

This prevents quotation marks from auto-surrounding URLs. Again, this breaks CKEditor for almost every application it is useful for, so I highly recommend NOT doing this under *almost* any circumstance.

Even though it is bad practice, adding it to the config.js rather than customizing core CKEditor code itself at least allows you to easily roll back the customization.

Comment: better check cross browser too. I just did a quick test in firefox and it automatically created quotes ( I wasn't using CKEditor)

Comment: I did test my implementation in the latest versions of IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I'm not sure how a browser would add quotes to an input field apart from anything the actual parser was doing, unless there is some sort of plugin installed in the browser?

Comment: Granted i tested in jsfiddle which may do some parsing at server when you run code also. Browser parsing stuff in DOM would be part of what CKEditor sees is what I was thinking